# Jetty automatically loads JSP support, how can that be turned off?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, jetty

In my logs I see the following when Jetty starts:

```
 +-WebAppContext@560c3014@560c3014/,file:/C:/MyProjects/ProxyServer/PrepayProxyWebsiteJetty/webapps/root/,webapps/root started
    +-{org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath=C:\MyProjects\ProxyServer\PrepayProxyWebsiteJetty\webapps\root\WEB-INF\classes, javax.servlet.context.tempdir=C:\Users\davidparks21\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-80-root-_-any-}
    +-{org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher=WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Nov 09 14:38:47 ICT 2010]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext, org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextScope=org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextScope@3ab6f7f5, org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT=Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 09 14:38:46 ICT 2010]; root of context hierarchy}
    +-SessionHandler@6f7918f0 started
       +-ConstraintSecurityHandler@47f08ed8 started
          +-[]
          +-/={TRACE={RoleInfo,F,C[]}}
          +-ServletHandler@77546dbc started
             +-[/*]/[]==0=>springSecurityFilterChain{}
             +-[/]=>default{resourceCache=resourceCache, maxCacheSize=256000000, dirAllowed=true, gzip=true, maxCachedFileSize=10000000, redirectWelcome=false, acceptRanges=true, welcomeServlets=false, aliases=false, useFileMappedBuffer=true, maxCachedFiles=2048}
             +-[*.jsp, *.jspf, *.jspx, *.xsp, *.JSP, *.JSPF, *.JSPX, *.XSP]=>jsp{logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG, fork=false, com.sun.appserv.jsp.classpath=<list_removed>, xpoweredBy=false, scratchdir=C:\Users\davidparks21\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-80-root-_-any-\jsp}
             +-[/]=>dispatcher{}
```

In my webapps web.xml I defined springSecurityFilterChain() and dispatcher(), but I did not define default and jsp.

It appears that JSP support is on by default, this should not be, I use velocity. Is there a way to disable this?

Also I see that there is a default which has dirAllowed=true, that makes me nervous, should it not be there?

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SPRING DISPATCHER SERVLET ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- Allows Spring to handle all web requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SPRING SECURITY HOOK ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- All web requests go through security validation -->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ BEAN SCOPES FOR WEB ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- Adds support for scoping beans as: 'request', 'session', and 'global session' -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jetty 7.1.2, JSP support will be on if the classes in lib/jsp are in Jetty's classpath, and off otherwise. The OPTIONS=jsp argument to start.jar just controls their presence in the classpath.

Another option to disable JSP support comes from the [mailing list](http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/disable-jsp-engine-when-starting-jetty-td17393.html). Essentially, the default descriptor for each deployed web app contains a JSP/Servlet mapping. If JSP is not required, then disable it for a given context by setting the `setDefaultsDescriptor` to `null`. For example:

```
WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
wac.setDefaultsDescriptor( null );
```

See the [WebAppContext documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.6.v20141205/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setDefaultsDescriptor%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

Comment: This is Jetty 7.2.0. I just noticed the odd looking log file that seemed suggestive that JSP support was on, but I haven't actually tried to make it work. I don't have any JSPs or a jsp folder anywhere.

Comment: I'm sure that in your jetty distribution directory that you downloaded that you have a lib/jsp directory, unless you manually deleted it.